# Background processes unable to pop() showDialog from Navigator

Tags: ios, flutter, navigator, showdialog

I'm trying to create a process whereby my app will pop up a showDialog box for a period of time, and then ONLY after receiving information from an online resource cancel out of the show-dialog.

I've done it with changing an entire new scaffold widget without any problems, and navigator.pop(); just pushes me back into the previous context without a problem.

However with a showDialog widget my Navigator.of(context).pop(); only ever touches the base screen.

I know how to have the show-dialog box close if I have a button in it, but the same like of code doesn't work.

Basically the context being passed into the Navigator.of(context).pop(); line isn't the same as the context of the showDialog box...  And I don't know why.

Code Sample:

```
<Code that decides when to call myDialog>

myDialog(context);

<Other code in a decision-tree although in the same root function>

if (condition) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}


  Future<void> myDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      <Code that shows Body of dialog box>
    ),
  }
```

So yeah, obviously the context being passed in is wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: It would help if you could post the whole snippet to give it some context.

Comment: I actually can't, for security reasons (which was why I provided what I felt were the most important parts of the code, obviously I may have been mistaken.) However I may try to re-create a minimal-recreation if this still remains an issue.  I did figure out a different resolution for the issue that uses a different process which I'm going to try first.